# Void reading of too heavy Excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to read a .xlsx file from MATLAB. I've firstly tried with a test.xlsx file, that you can see below

[image]

using this MATLAB code

```
filename = 'test.xlsx';
A = xlsread(filename);
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'B2:B4';
subsetA = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange)
```

that returns this output

```
subsetA =

 4
 5
 6
```

This is ok.

Problems occur when I want to read from a 7.5 MB datalog.xlsx file, that contains about 70000 rows per 22 columns (as you can image from the title is a datalog file). So, when I try to apply the same MATLAB code that you can see above, that happens:

```
filename = 'datalog.xlsx';
A = xlsread(filename);
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'B2:B4';
subsetA = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange)
```

That returns an empty value:

```
subsetA =

     []
```

What is the problem? I think the weight of datalog.xlsx could be a problem, but this seems strange, as I'm expecting that MATLAB should manage this kind of works.

Comment: As a possible alternative/lighter weight method, have you considered saving the excel file as a CSV and reading it like that?

Comment: I've already solved this problem by using a .txt file that contains the same values of the excel file and reading from that .txt file. 
I've posted this question because I want to understand why this code is not working